# how do I return to the same exact page after posting a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect, form-post

I'm posting data to a page called process.aspx that handles some business logic with the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    MyData.process(Request);
    Response.Redirect("")
%>
```

this page I will be calling from a variety of pages. Is there some way of knowing from which page my form was submitted? I was thinking something along the lines of writing:

```
 <form id="frmSystem" method="post" action="process.aspx?page=<%=  %>">
```

However I don't know what to write in between the `<%=  %>` to get the current page name. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the calling page URL and hold it in `Session` or `ViewState` for later use.

For example, in `Page_Load`,

```
Session["PreviousPage"] = Request.Url.ToString();
```

And then in your final event (perhaps Savebutton_Click or CloseButton_Click), you can do a redirect in either of these ways:

```
Server.Transfer(Session["PreviousPage"].ToString(), false);
```

or

```
Response.Redirect(Session["PreviousPage"].ToString(), false);
```

You can also get the URL of the calling page this way:

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
```

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's a nice feature for a website to send the user back from whence they came.

Comment: Be aware that Request.Url.PathAndQuery can be faked. The way to store the previous page in the session seems to fit best in this situation.

Comment: This one did it, I found the 'Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery' command! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in it in via a property like the `ReturnUrl` similar how a sign in page works.  This is kind of how you are doing it up there.

You could also try to use the `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` to see who referred you.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer is working just dandy, I merely need to use only the page name + the query string now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString` to get the URI of the referring page.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, is there a way to get only the page and query string out of this method? I'm trying it and its working just dandy, all I need is to take only the page name + the query string.

Comment: If you want the entire path with out the http: part, you can use Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.  If you actually want ONLY the page anme and query string, use System.IO.Path(Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath) + Request.UrlReferrer.Query